# using jconsole to monitor local java program

Tags: java

I am trying to use jConsole.I created sample MBean application and ran it from command line. I have opened jconsole but jconsole did not detect the local java process.Please find the screen shot of jconsole when I open it.

[image]

I have checked the jconsole documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html#gddaw) and jconsole has local process
What should I do to get java local processes detected by jconsole ? Java program I am running is [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1352/what-is-jmx-mbean-jconsole-tutorial)

I am running the program  on windows 7.

Comment: what operating system are you on?  if you are on *nix, you need to run jconsole as root or sudo in order to use the RPC connection method.  otherwise you have to connect via loopback socket.  on windows, it could be an administrative rights issue as well.

Comment: If you have multiple JVMs installed, be sure you run the program with the same JVM as you run the jconsole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have invoked wrong jconsole. I should have used jconsole in the Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin but I was trying with Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib ... Thanks for responses.